# Why is a "schema" different in MySQL and SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, schema

I am new to databases. I want to know why, when I create a schema, in MySQL it is a database, while in SQL Server it is a schema inside a database. Can anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because different vendors have different ways to describe, separate and delineate things and can even use the same words differently. MySQL for whatever reason (I think it is more inline with Oracle) calls schema and database the same thing, while SQL Server has a database that can contain multiple schemas. I don't know if you can declare either of them "more right" it's just a matter of knowing the differences, even if they aren't intuitive. One could check the ANSI standards I suppose to see which is more inline with what the standards body intended.

I don't know if you really have a shot at getting a legitimate answer to this question that will keep it on-topic, unless you can convince the MySQL and SQL Server team to come in and state why they chose the way they did (keeping in mind that the people who made these choices way back when are not likely to still be on their respective teams).

Comment: ahh ok thanks for the answer, can i have your opinion sir?? which do you prefer? mysql or sql server?

Comment: I'm a SQL Server guy. But that is a very subjective question, there are also plenty of MySQL folks around, so don't use my opinion to help you choose.

Answer (score 12):

**In SQL server**

A database schema is a way to logically group objects such as tables, views, stored procedures etc. Think of a schema as a container of objects. You can assign a user login permissions to a single schema so that the user can only access the objects they are authorized to access.
Schemas can be created and altered in a database, and users can be granted access to a schema. A schema can be owned by any user, and schema ownership is transferable.

For more details visit the famous sql authority blog
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/09/07/sql-server-importance-of-database-schemas-in-sql-server/

**In MySQL**

Creating a Schema is similar to creating a database.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-database.html

Comment: This explains the differences, which are useful, but the question is why are they different?

Comment: Thanks also for the answer, @AaronBertrand - yeah ur right, I already understand the differences between them thanks to all of your answers, and I am also curious why they are different